# Simple Fortran do Loop

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm very new to Fortran and have a simple loop question I wasn't able to find the answer to specifically anywhere.

If I have a loop like this :

```
do l = -0, 0
   ! do something 
   ! something else
end do
```

Does the loop ever get called? My first inclination would be no. But maybe there is a subtlety in Fortran I don't know about?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it. I'm surprised that it actually runs through once. Can you explain why that is? From the definition of their do loops, I wouldn't expect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A do statement is in the form:

```
DO do_variable = m_1, m_2 [, m_3]
```

where `m_1` is that initial parameter, `m_2` is the terminal parameter, and `m_3` is the optional increment parameter (default value is 1) has the number of loop iterations calculated as

```
(m_2 - m_1 + m_3) / m_3
```

which for your loop is evaluated as (0-(-0)+1)/1 = 1, for 1 iteration.

Reference: ISO/IEC 1539-1:2010 (Fortran 2008) Section 8.1.6.6.1

Example:

```
program test
implicit none
integer :: i
do i=1,1
   write (*,*) 'Iteration with i=',i
end do
end program test
```

Output:

```
% ./doloop1 
Iteration with i=           1
```